# List of tuples with hours and items in it (24 hour format hours convert into 12 hour format)

Tags: python, list, type-conversion, tuples

**Change hours in 24h format to 12h format and remain items**

```
[('00:00', ['a', 'b']), ('03:12', ['c']), ('23:02', ['gh'])]
```

I've tried to use datetime, but it didn't quite work out.

```
time = [datetime.datetime.strptime(t, "%H:%M").strftime("%-I:%M %p") for t in time]
```

From this:

```
[('00:00', ['a', 'b']), ('03:12', ['c']), ('23:02', ['gh'])]
```

I'm trying to get this:

```
[('12:00 AM', ['a', 'b']), ('3:12 PM', ['c']), ('11:02 PM', ['gh'])]
```

Comment: What happens with your attempt?

Comment: `t` is the whole tuple, not just the time part.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there, just change the first tuple element and leave the second as is:

```
time = [('00:00', ['a', 'b']), ('03:12', ['c']), ('23:02', ['gh'])]

[(datetime.strptime(t[0], "%H:%M").strftime("%-I:%M %p"), t[1]) for t in time]

# [('12:00 AM', ['a', 'b']), ('3:12 AM', ['c']), ('11:02 PM', ['gh'])]
```